# Best way to ground an Intersystem Bonding Termination (IBT)?

Tags: electrical

What is the best way to ground a IBT? To the main panel ground bar? directly to the UFER grounding electrodes?  Or to install the IBT on the meter base?

Comment: Can you not get access to the Grounding Electrode Conductor itself?

Comment: Yes, we can, house is still in rough-in stage...that's why I mentioned directly to the UFER ground as a potential (no pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

### D) None of the above

Most purpose-made Intersystem Bonding Termination devices are designed with a *lay-in lug* as part of them, designed to connect to a wire-type Grounding Electrode Conductor without disrupting the GEC, which is required by NEC 250.64(C) point 1 to be unspliced save for exothermic welds or irreversable compression splices.  As thus, I would do just that, mounting the device at a convenient point along the GEC and routing the GEC through the lay-in lug to make the connection.

If that is not an option, I would use a Burndy BDT mounted to the service equipment cabinet, with a minimum 6AWG bare copper bonding jumper inside the enclosure connecting the device to a ground bar.  This avoids having to reroute the GEC itself while still providing a convenient intersystem bonding termination point.

Comment: So would it be OK to simply run a ground wire to the UFER electrodes fro the IBT and call it good?   BTW, that was one of the above options in my OP.

Comment: Yeah, that works.  I thought your question implied attaching the IBT directly to the rebar stubup on the Ufer electrode or somesuch :p (which would be legal, but very, very odd)